# Add page to multiple PDFs in batch without messing with fonts

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to use Ghostscript to append a PDF as "last page" to multiple other PDFs. The problem I'm encountering is that Ghostscript walks through the whole PDF and does a bunch of font substitution.

I'm using the following batch script:

```
FOR %%G IN (*.pdf) DO IF NOT %%G==lastpage.pdf gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="output\%%G" -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH  "%%G" lastpage.pdf
```

Example Error:

```
Page 12
Substituting font Courier for GGCJBF+Courier.
```

I will also sometimes get other errors, like this:

```
jbig2dec FATAL ERROR decoding image: prevent DOS while decoding height classes (segment 0x00)
failed to create parsed JBIG2GLOBALS object.
**** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
**** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
```

All I need gs to do is append my lastpage.pdf to the existing PDFs *without* walking through the entire PDF I'm appending to, especially with font substitution, because I will not have most of the fonts other people are using in their PDFs.

Is it possible in gs to simply append without walking through every page of the PDF? Is there another tool that will allow appending of PDFs in batches without this issue?

Comment: Try [PDFToolkit](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/). The `server` version is a command line to do this kind of operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be aware that Ghostscript does not simply manipulate the incoming PDF file, so you aren't 'appending' a page. What it does is interpret the incoming file into marking operations, pass those to a device, and that device takes further action on them. Rendering devices write to a bitmap, pdfwrite reassembles the marking operations into a brand new file.

That's why it 'walks through the whole file', its the way it works. There are advantages to this (its possible to alter the file contents for example) and disadvantages.

Now if you are getting a font substitution for an embedded font, there's something wrong with the embedded font (or possibly you are using a really old version of Ghostscript with a bug). You could try a newer version of Ghostscript but you're never going to get away from processing the entire input file.

Why not try pdftk.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know gs worked that way, so thanks for explaining. PDFtk seems to do the job.

Comment: A similar problem I recently encountered: I have configured ghostscript-9.15 to avoid lossy encoding of images (-dColorImageFilter=/FlatEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false etc), but the images in the generated PDF are obviously encoded with a lossy encoder. Also, I get error messages such as "jbig2dec FATAL ERROR decoding image: prevent DOS while decoding height classes", which imply that a lossy encoder is used. Is there a way to make ghostscript never reencode the images?

Comment: Those messages (from what you post) are from the *decoder* which suggests your original image is a JBIG2 image, and thererfore monochrome. So the ColorImage controls won't affect it (it also suggests that the image is corrupted in some way). My first suggestion would be to use current code (9.18 at the time of writing) and if the problem persists, open a bug report, attach an eample and a clear description of the image which is 'obviously encoded with a lossy encoder'